# jQuery обработчкик ивентов

Tags: javascript, jquery, события, mouse-event

Всем привет!

Часто вижу конструкции *jQuery* такого типа:

```
$(document).on('click', '.somebtn', function(){});
```

Хотя сам всегда пользуюсь конструкцией:

```
$('.somebtn').on('click', function(){});
```

Есть ли между ними разница и если есть то в чём? Когда лучше использовать первую а когда вторую конструкцию?

Есть предположение, что первую лучше использовать когда не надо кэшировать сам элемент в переменную, а вторую, наоборот, когда этот элемент нужно кэшировать для дальнейшего использования.

Я всегда делаю так:

```
let $somebtn = $('.somebtn');
$somebtn.on('click', function(){});
```

И потом можно дальше пользоваться элементом без вызова *jQuery* селектора каждый раз чисто ради оптимизации.

Comment: Это не дубликат. Это вопрос, где требуется более более обширное описание поведения и почему происходит именно так

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, описание отличия вполне есть в ответе по ссылке.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, кроме того, данный вопрос на самом деле _уже_ а не _шире_, потому что тут только _on_

Comment: @Grundy вопрос Уже, но тема вполне себе обширнее и бОлее раскрываема, нежели одна строчка в якобы дубликате. Могут быть вполне себе нюансы. И объяснения этих нюансов. Что вмещается минимум на несколько абзацев

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, на самом деле отличие как раз одна строка: откуда ловится события - если от внутреннего элемента, то разница в том. что элемент мог быть добавлен динамически, если тот же элемент - то разницы нет. Нюансов нет.